# How can I change the color of clothing from dark to white in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, color

Is there any way in Photoshop to switch the color of dark clothing into white?

For example, I have the below image and I want to change the gown to white.

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend not to "photoshop" and let the model change her dress at first. If it were colour one you can transpose hue channel easily. Changing black to white is more brutal "photoshopping".

Comment: It would give you chance to move that weird shiny side-light too, or at least put a polariser on it to kill the shine on her face :/

Comment: Changing Black to White is not a change in color, it is a change in brightness.

Comment: This is not a photography question, but a photo manipulation one, so probably goes into Graphic Design.

Comment: I tried to change colors myself. But each method I tried, I was taking away something from the original. Reshooting again with the model would be the cleanest option

Comment: Photo manipulation of this sort seems on topic to me.

Comment: And black and white certainly are colors in this sense of the word color.

Answer (score 7):

Use a curves adjustment masked to the dress. Then pull up the blacks and shadows. Fine tune for color shifts. This is a two second job but done properly you'd have to do some edge refining and fine tuning:

[image]